# Nesteted/recursive compoenent error, unregistered component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use the component in itself with Nuxt.js component but in use get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

My code looks like this in `components/MyComponent.vue`

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>{{ a.content }}</h1>
    <MyComponent :child="a.child" />
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            a : {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/blah/')
        .then((res) =>
        {
            this.a = res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) =>
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Similar code worked with raw single page html page with vue.js, not sure how to name component before using here. How do I get it to work ?

Comment: Why would you import a component inside itself?

Comment: to render nested comment replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a name to your component in order to reuse it recursively, but you should control the rendering in order to avoid infinite loop:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>{{ a.content }}</h1>
    <MyComponent :child="a.child" />
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name:"MyComponent",
    props:['child'],
    data() {
        return {
            a : {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/api/blah/')
        .then((res) =>
        {
            this.a = res.data;
        })
        .catch((err) =>
        {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```